# I always get Internet connected the next day when I connect to a new machine, wired though?

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu

Every time I want to connect to a new machine I am not allowed to connect(wire) to the Internet. Others connected through the same router are getting the Internet uninterrupted. Some of the computers are connected via a switch, some others are connected directly from router (wire). The router is set to ´DHCP´ as well as the computer I am trying to connect. There is a information saying "the local area is limited connected to the network you may have no Internet or limited Internet".

When I checked the `ipconfig /all` on the machine connected properly and tried to apply same properties in the other seems does connect but not to the Internet (I do not get `!` mark on network indicator). This way I can get away with the limited connectivity message but I get no Internet.

If I connect this machine and leave it for around a day, the next day I get the connection properly. Is there something I can do so that I do not need to wait until the next day to get a connection? Most of the time I have to deal with different machines daily. It has been a pain in the a**. No matter which OS I try, it's the same.

Note: the connection is broadband to the router, Ethernet on machines, connected via wire. The router is a normal router mostly used in homes.

My settings on the running computer (connected via switch Netgear) are:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : netgear.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : netgear.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.xx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 216.146.35.35
                                       216.146.36.36
                                       192.168.1.1
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : den 5 december 2012 12:25:18
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : den 5 december 2012 13:25:18
```

One day later I got it connected. `ipconfig /all` shows me this (without default gateway)

```
 Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : netgear.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-F8-57-C4-6E

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : netgear.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet 10/100/1000B
ase-T Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : xx.yy.23.69
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : xx.yy.16.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 216.146.35.35
                                       192.168.1.1
                                       192.168.0.1
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, December 06, 2012 11:54:54 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, December 06, 2012 12:54:54 PM
```

Comment: More info about infrastructure please. What kind of internet connection (Wifi, DSL, Ethernet...)? What kind of Router?

Comment: @week          I have now edited the question, hope that is what you wanted to know, anything more I would be happy to let you know if I know what else I need to specify.

Comment: Cam we removed the less then nice language please?  Lets just stick to the facts shall we?

Comment: @Ramhound       I think you mean you would like to edit or want me to edit, sorry could not understand. You are more than welcome to edit if something seems wrong.

Comment: @tough - Yes.  Your question is half complaining half question.  Just look at the masked language, you should remove it, this is suppose to be a nice place to vist.

Comment: @Ramhound      yap, done, hope it is understandable and more clear now.

Comment: @marcel         I have updated the question details after I got internet connection today. Hope it adds more to my problem resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess, but I would look for statically set IP-Addresses on some computers, that my interfere with the DHCP provided ones form the router. The 1 Day-timeout may come from IP lease times of your router.

Please check all your devices for statically set IP-Addresses.

If this is not possible, you could try to reduce the lease times to just an hour for example and see if you get connected within an hour.

EDIT: To actually see if IP confusion is actually the problem, as suspected here, you could also first analyze the existing traffic on the network (using [LookAtLan](http://lookatlan.com/oldindex.html) for example) and find out which addresses are currently in use. Then connect the PC in question. If it then receives/has an IP of the previously used set, then you found the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am afraid , I do not have access to router login, I would not like to reset it every time I want to connect to another machine. Seems both the options I need to to get into the router settings, which I am not able to for now at least.

Comment: Not necessarily, It'll be sufficient to set all computer on network to optain IP via DHCP.

Comment: @tough, the first option does not need access to the router, but all the clients instead. And going this path would probably solve your problem better, as the second option is some bad kind of workaround anyway.

Comment: @Marcel from the above edited question part seems I get the lease on next day, so may be that is the reason I am not getting this connection working, just a guess It is the machine connected via switch.

Comment: @tough what happens if you make an "ipconfig renew all". Will it fix the problem? Will you get a new IP address?

Comment: @Marcel        "Clearing the ARP cache could not complete" info appears with ´repair´ option - using manuel ´ip configuration´. no media is connected while in ´DHCP´ with ´repair´. ´renew all´ with ´DHCP´says no media connected, with manual configuration says media 2 is not connected. Do not know what else can be done, Other machine also seems to be in DHCP connection, since sometimes we do not get access to internet on these regularly connected machines just a reset will will work, but problem of this kind happens rarely.

Comment: @tough sounds strange, but I think you found the spot to closely look at. Google for the info or ask a new specific question about that.