# I have Internet acess without default gateway IP. Strange for me

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, gateway

Every time I want to connect to a new machine I am allowed to connect(wire) to the internet the next day. Once connected I can disconnect for hours and I get the internet again. The router is set to ´DHCP´ as well as the machine that I connected yesterday.

my settings on running computer (connected via switch Netgear) where `Default Gateway IP` is available:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : netgear.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : netgear.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.xx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 216.146.35.35
                                       216.146.36.36
                                       192.168.1.1
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : den 5 december 2012 12:25:18
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : den 5 december 2012 13:25:18
```

today I got the internet connection leaving the machine open for whole night. `ipconfig /all` shows me this (without default gateway)

```
 Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : netgear.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-F8-57-C4-6E

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : netgear.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet 10/100/1000B
ase-T Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : xx.yy.23.65
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : xx.yy.16.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 216.146.35.35
                                       192.168.1.1
                                       192.168.0.1
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, December 06, 2012 11:54:54 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, December 06, 2012 12:54:54 PM
```

Is there anything I am missing? Some information how it happens and why ?
There is another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/515071/i-always-get-internet-connected-next-day-when-i-connect-to-a-new-machine-wired) I asked yesterday. Not being able to understand quite good I have changed the perspective & details in the question.

`route print` gives me this:

```
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     85.228.23.69     20
      85.228.16.0    255.255.240.0     85.228.23.69     85.228.23.69     20
     85.228.23.69  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     20
   85.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     85.228.23.69     85.228.23.69     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     85.228.23.69     85.228.23.69     20
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     85.228.23.69     85.228.23.69      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     85.228.23.69                2      1
Default Gateway:       192.168.1.1
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Your subnet mask has changed as well. You seem to be connected to a different network there. Do you have another (rouge) DHCP-server in your network? Or do you accidently mix up two independent networks?

Comment: have you checked the output of 'route print'? IIRC if a gateway is not specified for a network, packets addressed to remote networks are sent out the interface that is up. since you only have one up interface that makes the decision easy.

Comment: @FrankThomas   I have by now edited with results of `route print` hope helps identify the problem. Yes I do have two networks one from the switch and other from the direct router Netgear.

Comment: @gertvdijk It shows me the `Default Gateway` when use `route print`. Do not really understand what is going on.

Comment: interesting. assuming that your 'Attansic L1' interface is on the 85.228.23.x subnet (looks like it is) there is a default gateway defined. I note that the gateway address is 192.168.1.1, which is not a reachable network, but the exit interface is defined, which is sufficient as long as the end system does not attempt to arp the gateway.

Comment: @FrankThomas   Thanks, could you post it as a answer? I then tried to remove the manually added gateway´192.168.1.1´ , with ´ipconfig [release/renew]´ I got the new Gateway automatically. Would you please try to see the linked question please its a bit related, some hints may hit some solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see

```
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :    216.146.35.35
                                       192.168.1.1
                                       192.168.0.1
```

**192.168.0.1** appeared. Maybe it's really an interfrerence problem. Like @gertvdijk mentioned.

EDIT: Probably there's a misconfiguration on one of the two devices

Comment: May be so, I did myself added this ....0.1 DNS